# Setting default fetchSize for JOOQ queries

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jooq

Oracle's row prefetch size is 10, which is usually too small for the queries we execute via JOOQ. However, large parts of the application use JPA, for which we cannot increase the fetch size without risking increased GC activity.

I am trying to set a default fetch size for JOOQ queries such that

```
dsl.selectZero().from("DUAL").fetch();                // fetchSize: 100
dsl.selectZero().from("DUAL").fetchSize(123).fetch(); // fetchSize: 123
```

It is important that only JOOQ queries are affected. How do I achieve this? The only solution I came up with is the following:

1. make `AbstractResultQuery.fetchSize` accessible via reflection
2. Have an `ExecuteListener` whose `prepareEnd` callback

   - downcasts `ctx.query()` to `AbstractResultQuery` if possible
   - reads `AbstractResultQuery.fetchSize` via reflection

but this is obviously a violation of the API boundaries and might break one day. Is there a better solution?

PS: the same problem applies to other JDBC parameters like `queryTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting idea - it should be possible in jOOQ, but currently (version 3.7) isn't. There's a pending feature request for this: [#4753](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4753).

#### Workaround: Using reflection

For the time being, your reflection solution might be the right way. It's true that you'll rely on internals, but even if the field was renamed, there will (probably) always be a similar field somewhere

#### Workaround: Using JDBC type wrappers

Another solution is to provide jOOQ with a wrapper for a JDBC `Connection` (e.g. a subtype of jOOQ's [`DefaultConnection`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/DefaultConnection.html)), which returns a wrapper for a JDBC `PreparedStatement` (e.g. a subtype of jOOQ's [`DefaultPreparedStatement`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/DefaultPreparedStatement.html)), which implements your desired behaviour.

The above `DefaultXXX` types are designed as base implementations for wrappers that make overriding only parts of JDBC driver behaviour easy. It should be simple to write a [`ConnectionProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html) that exposes this behaviour only to jOOQ.